# Csrf post error when I'm trying to sign in

Tags: python, django, csrf, railway

On a local server, my `webapp` was working perfectly, but in production I get a `csrf post error` whenever I try to sign in or register.

In settings.py I have

```
django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware
```

I have tried pretty much every suggestion I have seen and cannot seem to get it working.  Any thoughts?

I tried adding all of these suggested by other posts I have seen :

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]

CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True


SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True

CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = 'mydomainname'

CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = "csrftoken_custom"

SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'Lax'
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'Lax'

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['*']
```

and the same error kept coming.
here is some of my login.html as requested:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'login' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="username-email">
        Username / Email
    </div>
    <div class="login-rectangle">
        <input class="login-rectangle-text" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Type Here" required>
    </div>

    <div class="password">
        Password
    </div>
    <div class="login-rectangle-2">
        <input class="login-rectangle-2-text" type="password" name="password" placeholder="**********" required>
        <div class="eye">
            <img src="{% static 'images/eye.png' %}">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="registerframe">
        <button class="create-user" type="submit"><span class="create-user-text">Sign In</span></button>
    </div>

</form>
```

This is the error log i am getting in railway logs : Forbidden (Origin checking failed - https://mywebappname does not match any trusted origins.): /login/

and this is the error i am getting in the debug mode:

Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

Help
Reason given for failure:

```
Origin checking failed - https:mywebapp does not match any trusted origins.
```

In general, this can occur when there is a genuine Cross Site Request Forgery, or when Django’s CSRF mechanism has not been used correctly. For POST forms, you need to ensure:

Your browser is accepting cookies.
The view function passes a request to the template’s render method.
In the template, there is a {% csrf_token %} template tag inside each POST form that targets an internal URL.
If you are not using CsrfViewMiddleware, then you must use csrf_protect on any views that use the csrf_token template tag, as well as those that accept the POST data.
The form has a valid CSRF token. After logging in in another browser tab or hitting the back button after a login, you may need to reload the page with the form, because the token is rotated after a login.
You’re seeing the help section of this page because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and only the initial error message will be displayed.

You can customize this page using the CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW setting.
settings.py file:
from pathlib import Path

('mywebapp' is the same url as my url in the CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN in my settings.py file)

Figured it out:
django 4.0 switched the CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS domain tag where you need to start it with a scheme: (usually http:// or https://)  when previously it was just the domain name.  Hope this helps others

Comment: Show us the signin page html template.

Comment: Also, show all the error wordings

Comment: see above, thanks so much for the replies.

Comment: Figured it out.  See above